# Set base url in nocms-codeigniter framework

Tags: codeigniter

How to set base url in nocms a codeigniter framework, can anyone please help me out with this question, I will be very much thankful to you.

Comment: add `url` in `application/config/config.php` -> `$config['base_url'] = YOUR SITE URL`

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter is a framework and No-CMS is built on Codeigniter framework.

In codeigniter you can access base url like this : 
`base_url()` and set base_url in your codeigniter `application/config/config.php`

and change

`$config['base_url'] = 'Your URL'`